# Android Facebook app: How long is the FB webview (Login webview) cookie valid?

Tags: android, facebook, cookies, access-token

I am currently developing an android app using the official android FB sdk : so everything from authentication/authorization(SSO) to API calls are made through the android FB sdk.

But for security reasons, I do not want to store my **access_token** on the phone. Now I have a little problem concerning the **cookie** stored by the **Facebook webview** (when you first log in). After quitting the android app or after killing the process, it seems that even if I don't store the access_token on the device, I still get access to the android app without providing credentials so It is probably the cookie.

Do you guyz know how long the **facebook's cookie is valid** ?

thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to manually remove the cookie when you are done with it.

```
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies();
```

That may be kind of a nuke on all cookies, so check the docs if you want more specific control on which cookies get removed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation of clearing cookies by Facebook itself.

```
    public static void clearFacebookCookies(Context context) {
        // setCookie acts differently when trying to expire cookies between builds of Android that are using
        // Chromium HTTP stack and those that are not. Using both of these domains to ensure it works on both.
        clearCookiesForDomain(context, "facebook.com");
        clearCookiesForDomain(context, ".facebook.com");
        clearCookiesForDomain(context, "https://facebook.com");
        clearCookiesForDomain(context, "https://.facebook.com");
    }



private static void clearCookiesForDomain(Context context, String domain) {
        // This is to work around a bug where CookieManager may fail to instantiate if CookieSyncManager
        // has never been created.
        CookieSyncManager syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
        syncManager.sync();

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

        String cookies = cookieManager.getCookie(domain);
        if (cookies == null) {
            return;
        }

        String[] splitCookies = cookies.split(";");
        for (String cookie : splitCookies) {
            String[] cookieParts = cookie.split("=");
            if (cookieParts.length > 0) {
                String newCookie = cookieParts[0].trim() + "=;expires=Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:01 UTC;";
                cookieManager.setCookie(domain, newCookie);
            }
        }
        cookieManager.removeExpiredCookie();
    }
```

If you have Facebook SDK connected to your project as lib. simply call **Session.getActiveSession().clearFacebookCookies(getApplicationContext());**